# SEO Friendly Way to Hide Vehicle Year Range

Tags: seo, hidden-text

I’m working on a site that sells products that fit cars of various years. We want the human visitor to see something like:

> Fits 1916-1933 Chevrolet Cars & Trucks

Unfortunately, this is poorly SEO’d. If someone searches for this type of product and includes “1928 Chevrolet” in their search terms, the search engine will likely not include this page because 1928 does not appear on the page. A human evaluates 1916-1933 and understands, but the search engine will not.

Obviously, we do not want to list every possible year for every possible car where the site visitor must see it. Hidden text is a no-no these days. So far, we have been unable to make it work nicely using accordions and the like.

Does anyone have suggestions how we can embed all the model years and vehicles without ruining the user experience?

Comment: Why don't you want to have a list of years where the visitor can see it? It doesn't have to be prominent.

Comment: One product fits dozens of makes, many models, and numerous years.  Listing all the data would be too much if visible.  Customers would get discouraged and leave the website.  Yet, we need the content so search engines can help the customer find what they are searching for.

Comment: "this product is designed for Chevrolets model years 1916-1917-1918-1919-1920-1921-1922-1923-1924 1925 1926 1927 1928 1929 1930 1931 1932 and 1933."   It's just one sentence. That doesn't seem excessive to me.

Comment: This seems like a UX problem, not an SEO problem. Solve the UX problem, and you also solve the SEO problem.

Comment: You're completely ignoring what I said about manufacturers, models, and years.  This product also fits Ford Model A, Ford Model B, Ford Model T, Auburn, Buick, Cadillac, Cord, Dusenberg, and dozens of others.  Each one has year ranges.  If we neglect the models and stick with makes, putting the year ranges on these will create a terrible user experience.  I was hoping for some expert Webmaster advice, not to just list the numbers and create a ghastly page.

Comment: You don't have to list every year range for every model.  There is likely to be a lot of duplication.    You only need the unique years.

Comment: I bet Google can figure out date ranges just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site in question uses WordPress and Shortcodes Ultimate.  The solution I chose:

```
[su_lightbox type="inline" src="#model-t-fitment"]1919-1927[/su_lightbox]
[su_lightbox_content id="model-t-fitment"]1919, 1920, 1921, 1922, 1923, 1924, 1925, 1926, 1927[/su_lightbox_content]
```

This solution, with the site's current template and CSS, shows what appears to be plain text of 1919-1927 to the user.  If they happen to click on it, which is not intended, a pop up with all the dates in the range appears.

**I believe this will provide the SEO I was seeking** by including all years, while relieving the burden of displaying all of this extensive data to the site visitor.

Comment: That depends on how and when the lightbox is created.   Googlebot doesn't click on anything, so of that text is only added to the DOM onclick Google won't ever see it.